# Application crash due to UIAlertController in ios 8

Tags: iphone, ios8, uialertcontroller

I am developing custom keyboard app and in this app want to show UIAlertController but it crash with following error.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController () of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'

I used following code...

```
     UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info"
                             message:@"You are using UIAlertController"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

     UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                    actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                    {
                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    }];
     UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                       {
                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                       }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So how can i solve?

Comment: I don't think you can call alertController in custom keyboard